# Fresh Ubuntu install mouse clicks only work once

Tags: mouse

my first post here. I’m basically a Linux noob although I’ve installed it a few times over the years and got the very minimal, minimal, basics down (if even that much). And it’s rusty at best.

I have with my Sony Vaio tap 11.  Fresh install, mouse click won’t work more than once after a login.  I used keyboard to get through install of Ubuntu 16 and once installed the problem is that mouse clicks on touch pad or with any USB mouse I try don’t work except the very first Time I click, (left and right) after a login.   I’ve searched around and around the web and can’t find anything quite like this.   I’m stumped.    Actually had the same problem a couple years ago with Ubuntu 14 and ended up giving up after a couple days. This time I thought I’d at least post.    I’m limping around with keyboard presses and my half broken touch screen atm.

Any help would be so tremendously appreciated

Thanks. Scott

Answer (score 0):

try to update your ubuntu with this commande "apt-get upgrade" 
but i recommand you to fully upgrade your ubuntu  "apt-get full-upgrade"
(if that dosen't work try to use the Software updater but only after upgrading)

Comment: Thanks. I’ve just finished updating as you suggested.  No change.  I played around a bit and noticed the one mouse click that I get is actually a click and hold.   I logged in.  Opened a terminal window and clicked on the title bar.  Now the cursor is dragging the terminal window around.   I assume then that the same thing is happening with the single right click I can perform.   This leads me to believe that the mouse click is stuck on.

Comment: Anyone able to offer any suggestions on this?